# Can kubernetes provide a verbose description of its scheduling decisions?

Tags: kubernetes

When scheduling a kubernetes Job and Pod, if the Pod can't be placed the explanation available from `kubectl describe pods PODNAME` looks like:

```
Warning  FailedScheduling  <unknown>  default-scheduler  0/172 nodes are available: 
1 Insufficient pods, 1 node(s) were unschedulable, 11 Insufficient memory, 
30 Insufficient cpu, 32 node(s) didn't match node selector, 97 Insufficient nvidia.com/gpu.
```

That's useful but a little too vague. I'd like more detail than that.

> Specifically can I list all nodes with the reason the pod wasn't scheduled to each particular node?

I was recently changing labels and the node selector and want to determine if I made a mistake somewhere in that process or if the nodes I need really are just busy.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can find more details related to problems with scheduling particular `Pod` in `kube-scheduler` logs. If you set up your cluster with **kubeadm** tool, `kube-scheduler` as well as other key components of the cluster is deployed as a system `Pod`. You can list such `Pods` with the following command:

```
kubectl get pods -n kube-system
```

which will show you among others your `kube-scheduler` `Pod`:

```
NAME                                          READY   STATUS              RESTARTS   AGE
kube-scheduler-master-ubuntu-18-04            1/1     Running             0          2m37s
```

Then you can check its logs. In my example the command will look as follows:

```
kubectl logs kube-scheduler-master-ubuntu-18-04 -n kube-system
```

You should find there the information you need.

---

One more thing...

If you've already verified it, just ignore this tip

Let's start from the beginning...

I've just created a simple job from the example you can find [here](https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/workloads/controllers/jobs-run-to-completion/):

```
kubectl apply -f https://k8s.io/examples/controllers/job.yaml

job.batch/pi created
```

If I run:

```
kubectl get jobs
```

it shows me:

```
NAME   COMPLETIONS   DURATION   AGE
pi     0/1           17m        17m
```

Hmm... completions 0/1 ? Something definitely went wrong. Let's check it.

```
kubectl describe job pi
```

tells me basically nothing. In it's events I can see only:

```
Events:
  Type    Reason            Age   From            Message
  ----    ------            ----  ----            -------
  Normal  SuccessfulCreate  18m   job-controller  Created pod: pi-zxp4p
```

as if everything went well... but we already know it didn't. So let's investigate further. As you probably know, `job-controller` creates `Pods` that run to completion to perform certain task. From the perspective of the `job-controller` everything went well (we've just seen it in it's events):

```
Events:
  Type    Reason            Age   From            Message
  ----    ------            ----  ----            -------
  Normal  SuccessfulCreate  23m   job-controller  Created pod: pi-zxp4p
```

It did it's part of the task and reported that everything went fine. But it's just part of the whole task. It passed actual `Pod` creation task further to the `kube-scheduler` controller as being just a `job-controller` it isn't responsible (and doesn't even have enough privileges) to schedule the actual `Pod` on particular node. If we run:

```
kubectl get pods
```

we can see one `Pod` in a `Pending` state:

```
NAME       READY   STATUS    RESTARTS   AGE
pi-zxp4p   0/1     Pending   0          30m
```

Let's describe it:

```
kubectl describe pod pi-zxp4p
```

In events we can see some very important and specific info:

```
Events:
  Type     Reason            Age                 From               Message
  ----     ------            ----                ----               -------
  Warning  FailedScheduling  20s (x24 over 33m)  default-scheduler  0/1 nodes are available: 1 node(s) had taints that the pod didn't tolerate.
```

so now we know the actual reason why our Pod couldn't be scheduled.

Pay attention to different fields of the event:

`From`: `default-scheduler` - it means that the message was originated from our `kube-scheduler`.

`Type`: `Warning`, which isn't as important as `Critical` or `Error` so chances are that it may not appear in `kube-scheduler` logs if the last one was started with the default level of log verbosity.

You can read [here](https://github.com/ravigadde/kube-scheduler/blob/master/docs/devel/logging.md) that:

> As per the comments, the practical default level is V(2). Developers
>   and QE environments may wish to run at V(3) or V(4). If you wish to
>   change the log level, you can pass in -v=X where X is the desired
>   maximum level to log.

Comment: Nice trick! However I don't see anything in there related to the current job that's stuck in Pending state that I'm trying to understand. I only see some previous jobs with logs `Unable to find backoff value...`, and that's the only log message that shows up when I look for pods with my name associated.

Comment: Did you try to look at `describe job` and/or `describe` or view `job's Pod` logs ? If you cannot find it in `kube-scheduler` logs you probably won't find it anywhere. You can try to change the default logs verbosity level of [kube-scheduler](https://kubernetes.io/docs/reference/command-line-tools-reference/kube-scheduler/) by providing `-v` flag and the desired number (higher number - higher verbosity).